# Why do Facebook iOS app is not receiving notifications for application requests?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, push-notification, apprequests

I am sending a request dialog like this:

```
[delegate.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

The notifications on desktop work great. But the Facebook iOS app doesn´t receive any notifications at all. (Neither in-app, globe icon with red number, or Push).

I see this behavior in [Path](https://www.path.com/) iPhone app. Here you send requests with dialogs and the Facebook iPhone client successfully receives the request notification:

[image: Path notification request]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is your app configured on Facebook's side as a mobile app? (i.e is there a link between your Facebook app ID and the app store? if not, I don't think requests from your app will be rendered in the iphone app because there's no way for the user to act on them)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Igy. I set it up as a mobile app, fill the app id and bundle, and enabled ´iOS native deep linking´. Would you like to answer that? If you want the points, for making that observation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want requests sent to your app's users to appear in the Facebook iPhone app, you need to configure your app settings so that Facebook knows the details of the iPhone version of your app - otherwise the requests aren't displayed as Facebook doesn't think the user can act on them.

The most relevant settings are 'iOS App ID' and 'iOS bundle ID', some of the other settings under 'Native iOS App'may be applicable also depending on how your app integrates with Facebook